# How can I disable the button on the earphones?

Tags: music-player

I keep accidentally pressing the button on the earbuds when it's in my pocket.

Any of these would be great for me:

1. Disable the button only when the device is locked
2. Disable the button always

Comment: Low-tech solution, but I just wrapped a bit of black tape round the button on the headphone cable on my last phone, worked a treat!

Answer (score 4):

[Headset blocker](http://www.appbrain.com/app/headset-blocker/com.idunnolol.headsetblocker) will disable those buttons.  It's a widget, not an app.

Comment: Thanks. Will accept if I can't find anything that will automatically do it when device is locked.

Comment: This one is **free**.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Galaxy Music [Button Disabler]](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rltmultimedia.serviceMusicButtonDisabler). It is the best solution for locking the music button.

It **costs** .99 cent though.

[image: screenshot]